# Como não inserir registros repetidos?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo um sistema de login no qual cada usuário cria uma `URL` que envia para o banco, só que preciso fazer com que não repita informações, caso já exista informação igual no banco ele retorne resultado `(URL indisponível)`.

**CÓDIGO DO INPUT:**

```
<input name="url" type="text">
```

**PHP:**

```
if($update==update) {
   $url = clean($_POST[url]);
   $updatenomedoevento = mysql_query("update usr_users set ... url = '$url' where ... ");
   echo("Suas informações foram atualizadas!");
}
```

Comment: Você conhece `UNIQUE`, `PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: Nunca utilizei ;s

Comment: Se eu entendi o que você quer, esta é a solução, dê uma estudada no assunto. Esse é um assunto bem básico de banco de dados. Será que você vai conseguir fazer coisas mais complexas? Você sabe bem o que esta função `clean()` faz? Ela provavelmente não limpa o suficiente o que precisa e este site estará altamente vulnerável à ataques.

Comment: Beleza, irei dar uma olhada.

Comment: Veja a resposta do colega @Maniero. Crie um índice único (UNIQUE) no banco de dados que ele lhe dará um retorno caso o registro que está tentando inserir já existir. Ou pode usar uma chave primária para fazer isso.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> A pergunta original é do tempo da lib `mysql`, a solução já está atualizada para `mysqli`, que é a maneira moderna de fazer, mas vale notar que a lógica é a mesma para qualquer interface para MySQL.

Sempre vai ter alguém propondo dar um `SELECT` para ver se determinado registro existe pra inserir depois, nem perca tempo com essas soluções porque geralmente quem faz isso não faz a mínima idéia do que seja uma ["race condition"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/70). Nada garante que não vá haver uma inserção por outro processo entre o `SELECT` e o `INSERT` seguinte.

O que precisamos (afinal, que é o objetivo a ser alcançado) é evitar a inserção de registros duplicados, e o DB já tem o mecanismo correto para isso, que é a chave única.

Primeiro, você deve criar um índice `UNIQUE` para a coluna `URL` (chaves primárias via de regra também são `UNIQUE`). Esta é sua garantia de unicidade.

O `UNIQUE` não está limitado a apenas uma coluna. Se fosse outra situação, aonde duas ou mais colunas não pudessem repetir, como um horário de médico, da mesma forma poderia criar um mesmo índice UNIQUE usando tanto a coluna do Id do médico quanto a do horário (o mesmo horário poderia ser usado por dois médicos diferentes, ou o mesmo médico atender dois horários diferentes, mas nunca dois agendamentos com mesmo horário e mesmo médico).

Depois de criado seu `UNIQUE`, basta comparar o [retorno do MySQL com o valor 1062 - ER_DUP_ENTRY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/5.6/en/server-error-reference.html#error_er_dup_entry) para saber se a URL é repetida:

```
    $chaveunica   =                 // aqui você recupera os
    $dadoainserir =                 // dados da sua aplicacao

    // Importante sanitizar os dados antes de montar a query

    $chavesanitizada = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $chaveunica)
    $dadosanitizado  = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $dadoainserir) 

    mysqli_query ( $db, " 
       UPDATE usr_users SET
       url = '$dadosanitizado'
       WHERE email = '$chavesanitizada'
    ");                             // Quebras de linha só para
                                    // facilitar leitura

    // Agora vamos obter o código de erro
    $errno = mysqli_errno($db); 

    // Vamos usar um define() só para não por o 1062 diretamente no if.
    // nada impede de usar if( $errno == 1062), só que fica menos claro.
    define("MYSQL_ER_DUP_ENTRY", 1062);

    // E finalmente, testamos se deu certo ou foi repetição:
    if ( $errno == 0 ) {
       echo( 'Suas informacoes foram atualizadas!' );
    } else if ( $errno == MYSQL_ER_DUP_ENTRY ) {
       echo( 'Este URL ja existe!' );
    } else {
       echo( 'Ocorreu um erro: ' . mysqli_error($db) );
    }
```

> Notar que arrumei seu código para evitar SQL Injection. Da forma como estava, um formulário malicioso poderia enviar dados para deletar seu BD, ou mesmo furtar informações.

Se quiser, você pode trocar o `if` por um `switch`.

Comment: Obrigado amigo irei testar, porém quando vou inserir o UNIQUE em url no sql dar o erro #1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'url'

Comment: Você tem que limpar o DB pra isso, ou preencher ele com URLs diferentes. Provavelmente ele já contem dados repetidos (mesmo os vazios nao podem repetir).

Comment: Obrigado, conseguir add o UNIQUE no MySql, agora vou para o código.