# Como faço para que não possa reservar um mesmo Equipamento para o mesmo dia e hora?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo um código de Locação de Equipamentos em Php, em geral o código já ta quase todo finalizado, mas na ultima etapa me deparei com um grande problema, eu desejo que o adm, pois é ele que faz as reservas, não possa reservar um mesmo equipamento duas vezes para o mesmo dia e para mesma hora. Então eu tentei fazer o seguinte no Evento

```html
include_once'conexao.php';
 if(isset($_POST['nomeprof']))$atrNomeprof = $_POST['nomeprof'];
 if(isset($_POST['loginprof']))$atrLoginprof = $_POST['loginprof'];
 if(isset($_POST['senhaprof']))$atrSenhaProf = $_POST['senhaprof'];
 if(isset($_POST['telefoneprof']))$atrTelprof = $_POST['telefoneprof'];
 if(isset($_POST['cpfprof']))$atrCPFprof = $_POST['cpfprof'];
 if(isset($_POST['disciplinaprof']))$atrDiscprof = $_POST['disciplinaprof'];
 if(isset($_POST['emailprof']))$atrEmailprof = $_POST['emailprof'];
 if(isset($_POST['nomeequip']))$atrNomeequip = $_POST['nomeequip'];
 if(isset($_POST['corequip']))$atrCorequip = $_POST['corequip'];
 if(isset($_POST['marcaequip']))$atrMarcaequip = $_POST['marcaequip'];
 if(isset($_POST['categoriaequip']))$atrCategoriaequip = $_POST['categoriaequip'];
 if(isset($_POST['id_equipamento']))$atride = $_POST['id_equipamento'];
 if(isset($_POST['id_professor']))$atridp = $_POST['id_professor'];
if(isset($_POST['data']))$atrdata = $_POST['data'];
if(isset($_POST['hora']))$hora = $_POST['hora'];
if(isset($_POST['hora2']))$hora2 = $_POST['hora2'];
if(isset($_POST['sala']))$sala = $_POST['sala'];


if(isset($_GET['reserva'])){

if($sql == "SELECT * from reservas where id_equipamento= '" . $atride . "' AND horario='".$hora."' AND dt_reserva='".$atrdata."' "){
    echo $sql;
    echo "<script> alert('Você ja Reservou esse equipamento para esse Dia e Horario') </script>";
  }
  else{

 $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO `reservas` SET `id_equipamento` = \"%d\", `id_adm` = \"%d\",  `horario` = \"%s\", `dt_reserva` = \"%s\", `id_professor` = \"%d\";",
$atride,
 $userId,
 $hora,
 $atrdata,
 $atridp);
 // echo $sql;
 mysql_query($sql,$con);

 echo"<script> alert('Equipamento Reservado com sucesso')</script>";
 }
}
```

Porem quando tento reservar um equipamento que ja está reservado no banco ele o código simplesmente ignora o segundo `if`como se ele nem estivesse ali. 
o `if` ignorado é esse

```
if($sql == "SELECT * from reservas where id_equipamento= '" . $atride . "' AND horario='".$hora."' AND dt_reserva='".$atrdata."' "){
echo $sql;
echo "<script> alert('Você ja Reservou esse equipamento para esse Dia e Horario') </script>";}
```

Ja analisei esse If varias vezes e tentei fazer alterações como em vez de `==` colocar apenas um `=` mas ai quando faço isso todas as futuras reservas, mesmo as que não então no banco vão entrar automaticamente no `if`

Comment: isso nao faz sentido nenhum: `if($sql == "SELECT * from reservas where id_equipamento= '....` - Você não está testando o resultado da query (você nem a executou).

Comment: Então qual seria a melhor solução para eu testar e executar a Query ?

Comment: mysql_query($sql,$con); e testar se trouxe resultado. Mas isso nao é a maneira correta. tem que por um indice único pegando as colunas desejadas, tentar inserir e verificar se deu erro de chave duplicada.

Comment: a solucao esta aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23014/70

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-num-rows.php)($query) para ver se já existe um resultado para sua query.

No caso:

```
$q="SELECT * FROM reservas WHERE id_equipamento= '" . $atride . "' AND horario='".$hora."' AND dt_reserva='".$atrdata."' ";
if(mysql_num_rows($q)){
    //Já existe na tabela.
    echo "<script> alert('Você ja Reservou esse equipamento para esse Dia e Horario') </script>";
}
```

Caso você tenha vários usuários em seu sistema este query não parece filtrar por usuário, ou seja, quando você buscar se qualquer usuário já reservou o equipamento para o dia e hora o sistema vai responder dizendo "você já reservou..."

Se você tem vários usuários precisará filtrar isso também para não dar futuros problemas.

E Só para lembrar, para futuros códigos seria melhor você utilizar o MYSQLI e não o MYSQL.

Answer (score 0):

O seu segundo "if" apenas está comparando o conteúdo da variável `$sql` com alguma string, neste caso `"SELECT * from reservas where id_equipamento= '" . $atride . "' AND horario='".$hora."' AND dt_reserva='".$atrdata."' "`.

O que você precisa fazer é:

1-executar a consulta que verifica se já existe uma reserva.
2-verificar se o retorno da consulta é maior ou igual a 1, pois neste caso já irá ter uma reserva (aqui é o seu segundo if).

Pegou a ideia?