# Verificar se o nome já está cadastrado no Banco de Dados

Tags: c#, mysql

Esta é uma tela de cadastro de Mangáka, então se eu digito um nome ele é adicionada sem problemas, porém eu quero verificar se já existe algum registro com esse nome.

Tabela:

```
create table tblMangaka(
                        idMangaka int(20) auto_increment primary key,
                        Mangaka varchar(500)
                       );
```

Código C#, seria no começo que faria a verificação, se texto do `txtNome` já está inserido na tabela tblMangaka.

```
strMysql = "insert into dbMangas.tblMangaka (Mangaka)values(@Mangaka);";

MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(strMysql, con);
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mangaka", txtNome.Text);

try
{
    con.Open();
    comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception erro)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu um erro:\n" + erro);
}
finally
{
    MessageBox.Show("Mangáka Cadastrado!", "Mangáka", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    txtNome.Clear();
    txtNome.Focus();
    con.Close();

    inserirCmbMangaka();
}
```

Comment: Apesar de outra linguagem, o DB é o mesmo, e a solução é a mesma - inserir e verificar se deu erro de violação de UNIQUE: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/23027/70 - inclusive tem um alerta importante no começo sobre uso indevido de SELECT nestes casos..

Comment: Existem outros problemas específicos do C#, mas eu nem tento mais porque quase todo mundo aprendeu errado, isso se espalhou de tal forma que nem tem mais como tentar arrumar nas pessoas. De qualquer forma pesquisando aqui tem e muita informação para começar criar códigos melhores, eu mesmo respondi várias vezes sobre isso.